# Where does task scheduler store its files in windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Where does  task scheduler store its files in windows server 2008?

Comment: Sounds like a Server Fault question to me....

Comment: Can you tell us the actual problem? Why do you need to know where the files are? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14):

Task information is stored in `%WINDIR%\System32\Tasks` (or `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`).  They appear to be stored as a single file per task, in an XML type format.

They are then referenced from the registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 2008, but 2003 stores them in `%WINDIR%\Tasks`.  If you open the properties on a scheduled task, the full path is listed right at the top of the window.

Comment: it's not there. and there's no full path listed

Comment: They probably moved it to a "shell folder". Is there an entry for it in the registry path `\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` (or "User Shell Folders") under local machine or current user? Have you tried searching your drive for `.job` files?